# How to check for certain characters using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to check for following characters in my string using regex but based on tutorials online and ]some questions on SO I havent been able to figure out a solution so far. Can anyone help. I would really appreciate it.

Here is my string:

```
0-9~!@#$%^&*()_+`-={}[]\|:”;’,./<>?ÀàÂâÄäÆæÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôÖöŒœßÙùÛûÜüŸÿ
```

I also want to allow single and double quotes in my string. So is there a way to do it.

Comment: Use `[chars]` to check for characters in a set. I can't believe the online tutorials don't explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to match the presence of any of those characters in the string you can just use this.

**Updated to include `'` and `"`

```
/["'\d~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+`\-=\{\}\[\]\|:”;’,\.\/<>\?ÀàÂâÄäÆæÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôÖöŒœßÙùÛûÜüŸÿ]/g
```

This is just a basic character class - http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

I would suggest you might be better to use a whitelist approach, rather than exclude characters, for example, `/[^\w\s"']/g` will match anything that is not `"` `'` `_` whitespace or alphanumeric

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it almost solves my problem but I am still not able to check for single and double quotes using this Regex

Comment: this might give you a better idea /[\d~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+`\-=\{\}\[\]\|:”;’,\.\/<>\?ÀàÂâÄäÆæÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôÖöŒœßÙùÛûÜüŸÿ]/g.test('kapil') returns false and /[\d~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+`\-=\{\}\[\]\|:”;’,\.\/<>\?ÀàÂâÄäÆæÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôÖöŒœßÙùÛûÜüŸÿ]/g.test('kap'"il') returns false as well

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate the answer.